# How to project a camera image onto a 3D-CAD model?

Tags: vector-analysis, image-processing

We want to project a camera image of a three-dimensional structure onto a CAD model of this structure in perspective to recover the depth information. The spatial position of the camera and the camera axis in relation to the CAD model are exactly known. The question is, what is the mathematical approach to find the depth information of the two-dimensional image?

We have created an approach using the IGES toolbox in MATLAB, but we encounter problems in implementing our data in the exemplary code.

Is there a different approach or tool?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Without knowing what you did exactly, it is not possible to tell if there is a "different" approach !

Comment: I did use the Iges Toolbox in MATLAB. The idea behind it, is the implement a CAD Model (*.igs) in a Matlab plot and then project Points/Data onto it. What you have to set is the Eye(camera) position, the viewing direction and the origin of the image. For the latter we dont have this information.

Comment: My approach was to connect several marker points, which are present in the CAD model as well as in the image, with lines. I placed the image along the camera axis at an initially arbitrary position, whereby the position to the CAD model is already aligned. The idea now is to move the image plane along the axis so that the lines meet in one point (vanishing point). If I then have this point or the position of the image plane, I should then be able to project each image point from the vanishing point along the respective ray onto the CAD model surface, right?

Answer (score 1):

When you render the CAD model as seen from the camera (in such a way that it perfectly registers with the real photo), the distance information is contained in the XYZ coordinates of the projected points and the position of the optical center of the camera.

Either your renderer is able to provide this information (which it uses internally), or you can implement a ray-tracing process that sends rays from the camera sensor to the model, until it hits the first surface.

If your renderer uses a Z-buffer, the latter contains the depth information, possibly transformed by an homography.